# get post types and plugin order

Tags: custom-post-types

I write a simple plugin to get all post types by using get_post_types. But it does not work.

```
$customPost = get_post_types(array(), 'object');
```

it returns default post types of wordpress.

When i install Woocommerce plugin, it does not show the custom post types of woocommerce ?

Does it relate to plugin order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post types in WordPress are not *saved* some where, they are *registered* everytime you request a page.

So to get all post types, you have to wait untill all post types are registered.

Normally, all post types are registered before the hook `wp_loaded` is fired.

So change your code in something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'my_get_all_types' );

function my_get_all_types() {
  // if you want only custom post types use '_builtin'=> false in the arguments array
  // 2nd argument should be 'objects' not 'object'
  $cpts = get_post_types( array( '_builtin'=> false ), 'objects'); 
  var_dump($cpts);
}
```